# Make Context.User.Identity.Name empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

How can I make my Context.User.Identity.Name equal to empty string after the user log-out. Because every time I go to Login Page the Context.User.Identity.Name is not empty. Thus, redirecting the user to the default page even though he already logged in.

My Log-Out code contains the following that I've researched but still doesn't make the Context.User.Identity.Name empty:

```
Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.User =
 new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);`
```

While my login code contains:

```
if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with class-asp. Remove **classic-asp** tag and add **ASP.NET**.